# No module named [mtcnn] - m1 Mac - python

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, importerror

I am trying to import the module `mtcnn` in VSCode.
I have run the following commands in the terminal:

```
pip3 install MTCNN
```

and

```
python3.8 -m pip install mtcnn
```

Which downloads MTCNN

[Terminal showing its already installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyFOP.png)

But when I try run my python file in VSCode, I run into this error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwi9C.png)

I am using python version 3.8.5 in VSCode. There is no red line error under the import line in VSCode so I'm confused why it's not working.

Comment: When you try to run your python file in vscode.... which copy of python is that and is it one of the ones in which you installed the module?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Open an **integrated terminal** in VS Code, run `python --version` to check if it's as the same as the one you selected for python interpreter, which is shown in status bar.
2. Run `pip show mtcnn`. If you get detailed information like name, version and location, **reload window** should solve your question.
   [image]
   If you get `WARNING: Package(s) not found: mtcnn`, it means no such module in your current selected environment, install it.
   [image]

Besides, to avoid messing up the global python environment, you may create a virtual environment. See [Create a Virtual Environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_create-a-virtual-environment).

Comment: i have a mac m2pro with the package installed and i still get the error